# System.Xml.XmlException: The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name

Tags: c#, xml

So I am using C# to create an XML document and using the System.Xml.Linq package.

I have a value I want to set in my xml that contains the character ':'

```
prefix:myVar
```

My code looks like this:

```
node.setAttribute("prefix:myVar", "myVarValue");
```

Where `node` is an `XElement`

I get the following exception when that line gets executed:

```
System.Xml.XmlException: The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.
```

I am guessing it's because the string `prefix:myVar` contains the character `:`. Is there a way around this?

Comment: See my answer from earlier today : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64227915/create-xml-from-sql-select-query/64239073#64239073 You need to use a namespace.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your remark setAttribute takes a XName not a XNamespace attribute.

Comment: The prefix is a namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:` is not allowed as part of the name because it's reserved to separate the namespace prefix from the local name. In this context, `prefix` is a namespace prefix and `myVar` is the local name.

The prefix is only valid if it is declared in the scope of the element it appears in, and it needs to have an associated namespace - which is omitted in your example, so I'll use `http://example.com/` to illustrate:

```cs
XNamespace ex = "http://example.com/";

var element = new XElement("foo",
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "prefix", ex),
    new XAttribute(ex + "myVar", "value"));
```

Note the name of the attribute is `ex + "myVar"`. This will create an element like this:

```xml
<foo xmlns:prefix="http://example.com/" prefix:myVar="value" />
```

I've explicitly added the declaration using `new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "prefix", ex)` above, but note this isn't required. If you omit it then one will be generated for you:

```cs
XNamespace ex = "http://example.com/";

var element = new XElement("foo",
    new XAttribute(ex + "myVar", "value"));
```

Will result in this:

```xml
<foo p1:myVar="value" xmlns:p1="http://example.com/" />
```

The two outputs are semantically identical.

Comment: But in your example is it possible to just get this `<foo p1:myVar="value" />`

Comment: No, that’s not well formed XML. The declaration must appear in this element or one of the parent elements.